# using charindex in a substring to trim a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

There is a column `name` from which I want to use to make a new column.
example:

```
name
asd_abceur1mz_a
asd_fxasdrasdusd3mz_a
asd_abceur10yz_a
asd_fxasdrasdusd15yz_a
```

The length of the column is not fixed so I assumed i have to use charindex to have a reference point from which I could trim.

**What i want:**  at the end there is always `z_a`, and i need to place in a separate column the left  part from `z_a` like this:

```
nameNew
eur1m
usd3m
eur10y
usd15y
```

The problem is that the number (in this example 1, 3, 10, 15) has 1 or two digits. I need to extract the information from `name` to `nameNew`.

After that i was thinking to make it easier to read and to output it like this:

```
eur_1m
usd_3m
eur_10y
usd_15y
```

I tried using a combination of substring and charindex, but so far without success.

```
SELECT  *
      , SUBSTRING(name, 1, ( CHARINDEX('z_a', NAME) - 1 )) AS nameNew
FROM    myTable
```

This is for the first step, trimming the string, for the 2nd step (making it easier to read) I don't know how to target the digit and place an `_`.
Any help would be appreciated. Using sql server 2012

### edit:

First of all thank you for your time and solutions. But your queries more or less even if they are working for 1 or 2 digits have the same problem. Consider this situation:

```
name
ab_dertEUR03EUR10YZ_A
```

if `eur` is two times in the string, then how can I eliminate this? Sorry for not includding this in my original post but i forgot that situation is possible and now that's a problem.

### edit:

test your queries here, on this example:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21610/1

**Please note** that at the end it can be any combination of 1 or 2 digits and the letter y or m.

Ex: `ab_rtgtEUR03EUR2YZ_A` , `ab_rtgtEUR03EUR2mZ_A`, `ab_rtgtEUR03EUR20YZ_A`, `ab_rtgtEUR03EUR20mZ_A`

Some values for testing: 
`('ex_CHFCHF01CHF10YZ_A'), ('ab_rtgtEUR03EUR2YZ_A'), ('RON_asdRON2MZ_A'),
('tg_USDUSD04USD5YZ_A');`

My understanding of your queries is that they perform something simillar to this (or at least they should)

```
ex_CHFCHF01CHF10YZ_A -> ex_CHFCHF01CHF10Y -> Y01FHC10FHCFHC -> Y01FHC -> CHF01Y -> CHF_01Y
RON_asdRON2MZ_A      ->  RON_asdRON2M     -> M2NORdsa_ron   -> M2NOR  -> RON2M  -> RON_2M
```

Comment: What a horrible idea to store data in such obfuscated manner. You are doing good replacing this with separate columns. However, 'eur_1m' is still a multiple-part information. Better store the parts separately: currency = 'EUR', months (?) = 12.

Comment: thank you, but i'm affraid it has to be in that format so i could later join it with other tables. Actually, i'm splitting it later as you said, but for now I need it like this

Comment: Sometimes one is bound to such weird formats (third party cmponents, interface data...) But @ThorstenKettner is right. You should seprate the information into atomic parts if you need to sort/query/aggregate them somehow in the future...

Comment: @Shnugo yes, you are right. I will do it like that for a future implementation but as I already said, don't have a choice now.

Comment: When it's just something to link records, then you shouldn't care about it's meaning. When it has a meaning on the other hand, then you should have separate columns. You could still join. Instead of `where a.name = b.name` you'd have `where a.currency = b.currency and a.months = b.months ...`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner good point. Will do it like that later, but now I have to deal with this, any solution/suggestions on how I could achieve what I described in the question?

Comment: In addition to @ThorstenKettner: You can keep your "name" and still put the parsed information in extra columns for future usage...

Comment: If you need both, the values and the key, then make the key a computed column built from the real columns.

Comment: @CM2K, did you check my answer? It delivers exactly the string you want, look in the final output, last column...

Comment: @ will check it in a bit, trying to check all the answers and i'm trying to test them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for one or two digits:

```
stuff(case
        when name like '%[0-9][0-9]_z[_]a'
          then left(right(name, 9), 6)
        when name like '%[0-9]_z[_]a'
          then left(right(name, 8), 5)
      end, 4, 0, '_')
```

Comment: @CM2K: And in order to insert an underline at position 4 use STUFF:  `stuff(left(right(name, 9), 6), 4, 0, '_')`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I totally forgot about the expected result, added it, thanks

Comment: @dnoeth, It won't change a lot, but the underscore in "a_z" should be escaped like `'%[0-9][0-9]_z[_]a'`, otherwise it would find other characters too. One upvote from my side...

Comment: @Shnugo: Correct, another change, it's easier if the OP provides a fiddle with some real data :-)

Comment: I tested all solutions and yours it the shortest and way more importantly, works as expected. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `substring` , `reverse` and `charindex`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f3dc/1)

```
select substring(namenew,1,3) + '_' + substring(namenew, 4, len(namenew))
from (
select 
case when name like '%[0-9][0-9]_z[_]a' then 
reverse(substring(reverse(name), charindex('a_z',reverse(name)) + 3, 6)) 
     when name like '%[0-9]_z[_]a' then 
reverse(substring(reverse(name), charindex('a_z',reverse(name)) + 3, 5)) 
end as namenew
from myTable 
) t
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tested it and it partially works. the problem is that if i have 2 digits say `asd_abceur10yz_a` the result is `ur10y` and it should be `eur10y`. So your query isn't adapting to 2 digits. Also, for the 2nd part, after getting the correct result, I need to transform it from `eur10y` to `eur_10y`

Comment: see the edited version which handles 2 digit occurences as well.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately it give the same result. ex: `ur10y` instead of `eur10y` if it has 1 digit it works fine and gives `eur1m`

Comment: try the latest one..changed the order of `case` statements

Comment: just tried it, does this: nameNew: `ur30y` then `ur3_0y` . for 1 digit nameNew: `eur1m` then `eur_1m` . So for 1 digit it works great, for 2 not so much

Comment: see the fiddle where it is working for 2 digits as well

Comment: ok, strange. Ok, i'll give you an example with the real format, just going to change some letters for security reason. `ab_abcursk12EUR10YZ_A`. Saw the fiddle, looks like it's working, but when i try it, it doesn't

Comment: i got `EUR_10Y` in the fiddle with your example. not sure why it doesn't work for you

Comment: please test your query with these values. Doesn't work: `('ex_CHFCHF01CHF10YZ_A'), ('ab_rtgtEUR03EUR2YZ_A'), ('RON_asdRON2YZ_A'),
('tg_USDUSD04USD5YZ_A')`

Comment: see the updated fiddle.it should work for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
declare @tbl TABLE(name VARCHAR(100));
insert into @tbl VALUES
 ('asd_abceur1mz_a')
,('asd_fxasdrasdusd3mz_a')
,('asd_abceur10yz_a')
,('asd_fxasdrasdusd15yz_a')
,('ab_dertEUR03EUR10YZ_A');

WITH CutOfThreeAtTheEnd AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(name,LEN(name)-3) AS nameNew
    FROM @tbl
)
,Max6CharsFromEnd AS
(
    SELECT RIGHT(nameNew,6) AS nameNew
    FROM CutOfThreeAtTheEnd
)
SELECT nameNew  
      ,FirstNumber.Position
      ,Parts.*
      ,Parts.FrontPart + '_' + Parts.BackPart AS FinalString
FROM Max6CharsFromEnd 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT MIN(x) 
    FROM
    (
              SELECT CHARINDEX('0',nameNew,1) AS x
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('1',nameNew,1)
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('2',nameNew,1)
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('3',nameNew,1)
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('4',nameNew,1)
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('5',nameNew,1)
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('6',nameNew,1)
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('7',nameNew,1)
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('8',nameNew,1)
        UNION SELECT CHARINDEX('9',nameNew,1)
    ) AS tbl
    WHERE x>0
) AS FirstNumber(Position)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(nameNew,FirstNumber.Position,1000) AS BackPart
                  ,SUBSTRING(nameNew,FirstNumber.Position-3,3) AS FrontPart) AS Parts
```

this is the result:

```
nameNew    Position BackPart    FrontPart   FinalString
ceur1m     5        1m          eur         eur_1m
dusd3m     5        3m          usd         usd_3m
eur10y     4        10y         eur         eur_10y
usd15y     4        15y         usd         usd_15y
EUR10Y     4        10Y         EUR         EUR_10Y
```

Comment: wow, this is great! thank you, but can I do this in a simpler way somehow? or is this it

Comment: Well, you could put this in an UDF and call it like `SELECT dbo.MyFunction(TheName)` to retrieve the output as an one-liner...

Comment: tested your solution and it works for most of them. But i also need to take into consideration the situation in which i'm having a group of characters present two times (and i do have it), what can i do then? example: name: `ab_dertEUR03EUR10YZ_A` you see? i have `eur` 2 times and your query returns : position `11` , backpart `03eurk10y` , frontPart `eur` , nameNew `ab_dertEUR03EUR10YZ`, position 11, backpart `03EURK10Y`, frontPart `eur`, finalString `eur_03eur10y`. Ps: we live in the same city, but my german is bad

Comment: @CM2K, there's a second CTE now, cutting this down to a max length from the back side. Now your new string is cut correctly...

Comment: will test your solution in detail tomorrow.

Comment: tested your solution, i'm affraid it doesn't work as intended. Please see my fiddle and try to apply your query to it. I did, had no luck  (tried your solution directly to the server, the fiddle there uses another solution, but anyway, it's a good playground)

Comment: this is what i get using your code: http://imgur.com/nS83qf7  for these values: `('ex_CHFCHF01CHF10YZ_A'), ('ab_rtgtEUR03EUR2YZ_A'), ('RON_asdRON2YZ_A'),
('tg_USDUSD04USD5YZ_A')`

Comment: @CM2K. Hi, cannot answer at the moment. I'll have a look at this later.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help, here is a fiddle with your code and schema built. I only replaced the values I want to test it with. For some reason it doesn't run but i ran it on the server and it yielded the results from the image posted in the comment above. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bb24

Comment: @CM2K, I just wanted to write, that you should go with go with the solution of dnoeth, but you did so already, good choice! Please - for a next question - try to give all details from the beginning :-)

Comment: thank you for the help, i upvoted yours because i learned something from your query. Sorry for not making it a complete question but had no idea the way people would approach this (eg: reverse the string, just why?). I will do my best to write better questions from now on